# $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt n \cdot\sin\frac{1}{n^2} $ converges or not?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to study the convergence of
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt n \cdot \sin\frac{1}{n^2} $$
I know each term of the series is positive so the series converges or diverges at +$\infty$.
The limit of the sequence for n to +$\infty$ is zero so the series might converge but I can say anything at this point. 
I know that
$$ \sqrt n \cdot \sin\frac{1}{n^2} = \sqrt n \cdot\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}} \cdot \frac{1}{n^2} = n^{-\frac{3}{2}} \cdot\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$
So if I compare my series with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^{\frac{3}{2}}$ using asymptotic convergence criteria
$$ \frac{\sqrt n \cdot \sin\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}} = \frac{\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}} \cdot\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}}{\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}} = \frac{\sin\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$
that goes to 1 for n to infinity and the two series have the same behavior. 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ is generalized armonic series and it converges because of the exponent > 1, so the series of the exercises converge.

Is it correct or not?

Comment: Yes, seems correct to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This converges; just note that
$$\sin\frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{1}{n^2}$$
for positive $n$ so
$$\sqrt{n} \sin\frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{1}{n^{\frac32}}$$
and your series converges to some value less than $\zeta\left(\frac32\right) \approx2.61$.

Comment: You should probably add an absolute value

Comment: note that $\sin$ won't change sign though around $0^+$ so absolute value not really required.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin t \sim t$ for $t\to 0$, you have:
$$ \sum_{n\ge 1} \sqrt n\sin\left(\frac{1} {n^2} \right )\sim \sum_{n\ge 1} \sqrt n\frac{1} {n^2}=\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1 }{n^{3/2} }$$
and the last series converges because $3/2>1$.